# How do I copy over all the relationships from one node to another?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data, spring-data-neo4j

**Background**

I have an abstract class called Invoke

It can be instantiated as 2 separate classes that extend invoke: bigInvoke and smallInvoke.

I am trying to make an API that has an Invoke PUT request that allows the user to change the class of their invoke from big to small or vice versa.

**My Code So Far**

The BigInvoke.java looks like:

```
@NodeEntity
public class BigInvoke extends Invoke {
    private String command;

    public BigInvoke(){
        this.invokeType = InvokeType.BigInvoke;
    }

    /**
     * @return the command
     */
    public String getCommand() {
        return command;
    }

    /**
     * @param command the command to set
     */
    public void setCommand(String command) {
        this.command = command;
    }
}
```

And, in my invokeService.java I have:

```
    @Override
    public Invoke update(UUID uuid, Invoke invoke) {
        Invoke i = find(uuid);
        i.setInvokeType(invoke.getInvokeType());
        invokeRepository.save(i);
        return invoke;
    }
```

**Problem 1**

But this just changes the value of the variable `invokeType` it doesn't actually change the class of the `invoke`.

How do I make this class change?

---

**My Code for attempt #2**

```
    @Override
    public Invoke update(UUID uuid, Invoke invoke) {
        Invoke i = find(uuid);
        UUID oldUUID =  i.getUuid();
        //make new one
        Invoke newInvoke = new Invoke();
        newInvoke.setInvokeType(invoke.getInvokeType());
        //Delete old one
        invokeRepository.deleteById(i.getUuid());
        newInvoke.setUuid(oldUUID);
        invokeRepository.save(newInvoke);
        return newInvoke;
    }
```

**Problem with #2**

This one works in the sense that the entity now has all the attributes that I want, but the `deleteById` deletes all the references to my Invoke. So my `newInvoke` no longer has the relationships of the older invoke. So, it doesn't really work.

**Question**

How do I change the class of my entity and keep all the relationships and the UUID?

**Edit 1 SmallInvoke Code**

```
@NodeEntity
public class SmallInvoke extends Invoke {
    private String smallCode;

    public SmallInvoke() {
        this.invokeType = InvokeType.SmallInvoke;
    }

    /**
     * @return the smallCode
     */
    public String getSmallCode() {
        return smallCode;
    }

    /**
     * @param smallCode
     *            the smallCode to set
     */
    public void setSmallCode(String smallCode) {
        this.smallCode = smallCode;
    }
}
```

**EDIT 2 Info on InvokeRepository**

InvokeRepository extends GenericRepository

GenericRepository extends Neo4jRepository

Comment: what diferebce between small and big invoke. Could be in same table and you will use @Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
@DiscriminatorColumn(name = “Publication_Type”)

Comment: @Peter1982 I have added some more info in edits 1 & 2, let me know if that helps

Comment: You cannot change the class of an existing object.  The best you can do is create a new object of the desired class and copy the instance data over.